# Ошибка при установке win32gui: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32.distutils.command'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-3.8, win32gui

во время установки win32gui выводит ошибку, не могу разобраться помогите пожалуйста(я как-то давно меня формат 1го из файлов питон на utf-8(у меня была ошибка и я думал что это из-за этого) и теперь я думаю что из-за этого изменения у меня и выдает ошибку)

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\3.14здец\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\3.14здец\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' get_requires_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\35138~1.14\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4w170le6'
       cwd: C:\Users\3.14здец\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n5uag6pi\win32gui
  Complete output (22 lines):
  Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
  SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 0: invalid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 7)
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\users\3.14здец\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 257, in <module>
      main()
    File "c:\users\3.14здец\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 240, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "c:\users\3.14здец\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 91, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
    File "c:\users\3.14здец\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 146, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
    File "c:\users\3.14здец\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 127, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "c:\users\3.14здец\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 236, in run_setup
      super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
    File "c:\users\3.14здец\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 142, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 27, in <module>
      from win32.distutils.gui import win32gui_build_ext
    File "C:\Users\3.14здец\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n5uag6pi\win32gui\win32\distutils\gui.py", line 6, in <module>
      from .command import win32_build_ext
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32.distutils.command'
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\3.14здец\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\3.14здец\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' get_requires_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\35138~1.14\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4w170le6' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Как говорил один известный проктолог - господа, темно не только у негра в жопе, но и на этом скриншоте.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: спасибо, я исправил.

Comment: но ошибку нет (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно [ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52812481/5909792) `win32gui` не поддерживает 3.8 версию (думаю, до сих пор и 3.7)

Попробуйте установить [pywin32](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32):

```
pip install pywin32
```

Домашняя страница [win32gui на pypi](https://pypi.org/project/win32gui/) ведет на страницу https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/, поэтому, думаю они должны быть совместимыми

Comment: Спасибо огромное, не знал!

Comment: @livertoy, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)