# Перемещение окон на второй виртуальный рабочий стол в Win10

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, desktop

У меня есть несколько запущенных, из автозагрузки, приложений ConEmu (8 штук). Их руками переношу на второй рабочий стол, что неудобно.

Хочу автоматизировать перемещение окон на второй рабочий стол.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Действия:

- Для перемещения окон использую модуль [pyvda](https://pypi.org/project/pyvda/) (`pip install pyvda==0.0.8`)
- Для поиска запущенных процессов `ConEmu` использую [psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/)
- Для работы с окнами использую [win32gui](https://pypi.org/project/win32gui/) и [pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/). Они нужны для получения хэндлеров окон (`hwnd`) у процессов, чтобы по ним можно было перенести окна

Установка дополнительных модулей:

```
pip install pyvda
pip install psutil
pip install win32gui
pip install pywin32
```

[Реализация:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/4ce077e177eec251b864f1cfcc159e8c4aa81f21/update_ConEmu_start_task/move%20ConEmu%20to%20second%20desktop.py#L37)

```
import psutil
import pyvda
import win32gui
import win32process


NEED_WINDOW_DESKTOP_NUMBER = 2


def get_hwnd_for_pid(pid: int):
    def callback(hwnd: int, hwnds: list):
        if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd) and win32gui.IsWindowEnabled(hwnd):
            _, found_pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)
            if found_pid == pid:
                hwnds.append(hwnd)
                return True
        return True

    hwnds = []
    win32gui.EnumWindows(callback, hwnds)
    return hwnds[0] if hwnds else -1


for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if not proc.is_running() or proc.name() != 'ConEmu.exe':
        continue

    hwnd = get_hwnd_for_pid(proc.pid)
    if hwnd == -1 or pyvda.GetWindowDesktopNumber(hwnd) == NEED_WINDOW_DESKTOP_NUMBER:
        continue

    print(f'Moved window (pid={proc.pid}) to window desktop #{NEED_WINDOW_DESKTOP_NUMBER}')
    pyvda.MoveWindowToDesktopNumber(hwnd, NEED_WINDOW_DESKTOP_NUMBER)
```

#### UPD. `AttributeError: module 'pyvda' has no attribute 'GetWindowDesktopNumber'`

В новых версиях `pyvda` (на текущий момент это версия `0.2.4`) будет ошибка `AttributeError: module 'pyvda' has no attribute 'GetWindowDesktopNumber'`, т.к. поменялось API библиотеки, [теперь решение будет такое](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/99ea332d5f8d3e68c502aeeee2aeea5f23134220/update_ConEmu_start_task/move%20ConEmu%20to%20second%20desktop.py#L37):

```
import psutil
import win32gui
import win32process
from pyvda import AppView, VirtualDesktop


NEED_WINDOW_DESKTOP_NUMBER = 2


def get_hwnd_for_pid(pid: int):
    def callback(hwnd: int, hwnds: list):
        if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd) and win32gui.IsWindowEnabled(hwnd):
            _, found_pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)
            if found_pid == pid:
                hwnds.append(hwnd)
                return True
        return True

    hwnds = []
    win32gui.EnumWindows(callback, hwnds)
    return hwnds[0] if hwnds else -1


for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if not proc.is_running() or proc.name() not in ['ConEmu.exe', 'ConEmu64.exe']:
        continue

    hwnd = get_hwnd_for_pid(proc.pid)
    app_view = AppView(hwnd)

    # If the window is already on the desired desktop
    if hwnd == -1 or app_view.desktop.number == NEED_WINDOW_DESKTOP_NUMBER:
        continue

    print(f'Moved window (pid={proc.pid}) to window desktop #{NEED_WINDOW_DESKTOP_NUMBER}')
    app_view.move(VirtualDesktop(NEED_WINDOW_DESKTOP_NUMBER))
```

Comment: Вы забыли указать, что модуль `win32gui` не поддерживается на python версии 3.7 и выше (что вы указали в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1114499/361777) ответе, кстати). А само решение полезное =)

Comment: @Евгений  нет, у меня в 3.8 в винде 7 работало

Comment: @Евгений, спасибо :) Ну, там среди устанавливаемых есть `pywin32`, так что нормально будет :)